# What is the compiler-defined macro for WASM?

Tags: c, webassembly

What is the macro that `clang` and/or `gcc` would define when compiling for a WASM backend?

To clarify, one can write platform-specific code using macros the compiler defines like so:

```
#if _WIN32
// Windows-specific code
#elif __linux__
// Linux-specific code
#elif __APPLE__
// macOS-specific code
#else
#error Unsupported platform
#endif
```

I would like to do the same thing specifying WebAssembly as one of the potential backends.

Comment: Most likely, there isn't a way.  Whatever mechanism there is will be controlled by the compiler that supports WASM and will be documented in its manual.  Without you stipulating which compiler you use that supports WASM, you're unlikely IMO to get a useful answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per @Jonathan Leffler's comment, there does not appear to be a standard macro that is defined across compilers.

My current solution for working with different compilers is to create a separate build job for WASM that defines a macro. For `gcc` and `clang`, it passes the flag `-D__WASM__` to define a `__WASM__` macro.

In my setup, I just change an environment variable and my build script selects the appropriate build flags.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
__EMSCRIPTEN__
```

See [this](https://emscripten.org/docs/compiling/Building-Projects.html#detecting-emscripten-in-preprocessor).

Edit:

`emcc -E -dM - < /dev/null`

Gives other defines related to wasm:

```
#define __wasm 1
#define __wasm32 1
#define __wasm32__ 1
#define __wasm__ 1
```

I'm not sure if they are added by clang or by emscripten.

Comment: I'm not using Emscripten, so I assume this macro wouldn't be defined.

Comment: ho, ok. So I also listed some defines reported by emscripten wrapper emcc, hopefully they are defined by clang. You can also try "clang --target=wasm32 -E -dM - < /dev/null" on your side.